# DoublyLinkedList constructor

Tags: data-structures

```
    public DoublyLinkedList() {
        header = new Node<>(null,null,trailer);
        trailer = new Node<>(null,header,null);
    }
```

```
    public DoublyLinkedList() {
        header = new Node<>(null, null, null);      // create header
        trailer = new Node<>(null, header, null);   // trailer is preceded by header
        header.setNext(trailer);                    // header is followed by trailer
    }
```

Above are the two different constructors of DoublyLinkedList. The first one is my idea and the second is what is written in the textbook. I wonder if my code works out.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work unfortunately because at the time the header is created, the trailer is not yet available.

Comment: Thank you! And I have a follow-up question. I already have the code: [private Node<E> trailer;] written before the constructor. My code does not work because the trailer is declared after the header